# React-Virtualized list with sticky headers

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I'm trying to use react virtualized to render a list, but some of the elements in the list act as headers like

```
[Category 1,
 item1,
 item2
 item3,
 Category2,
 item1,
 item2,
 item3]
```

I'd like to keep the current category stickied at the top of the rendered list, if anyone knows how to do that? (like it always showing category 1 until I've scrolled down far enough that category 2 comes to the top, at which point category 1 disappears and category 2 stickies at the top).

I've looked into https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-virtualized-sticky-tree, but it doesn't seem to offer things like [CellMeasurer](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/CellMeasurer.md) and such that react-virtualized does.